# for loop and variable scope

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do something.
I have a variable that acts as a HTML template, and insert properties from an array of objects.  Simple code below:

```
i = 0;
v =  "<li>",
v += array[i].prop,
v += "</li>";
```

Array of objects:

```
array = new Array();
array[0] = { name: "1",
             prop: "Property 1"
           }
array[1] = { name: "2",
             prop: "Property 2"
           }
```

This is the bit thats getting me:

```
for (; i < array.length ;) {
    i += 1;
    console.log(i);
    $("body").append(v);
}
```

i returns as 0 and 1 in the console, but the prop value returns as "Property 1" twice.
As far as I'm aware, since I haven't declared i in the for loop it should be returning the new value of i to the originally declared variable.  This is obviously a scope issue that I'm missing/don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "returning the new value of `i` to the originally declared variable"?

Comment: This is probably not a scope issue so much as a an order of execution issue. In what order is the actual code? (In the code you posted, you are using `i` in the assignment to `v` before you are assigning anything to `i`. Is that what actually happens?) Do you have any `var` declarations?

Comment: @cHao: i increases with each iteration, but isn't declared within the loop so its sits globally to the loop (I don't know the proper terminology...)

Comment: @TedHopp: The code is essentially that with a much longer "v" variable and a much longer set of object properties.  I can get this to work if I declare i like this: for (i = 0; ....; i++) and I move the variable v into the loop scope, but this isn't ideal for this situation.

Comment: @JamieStrauss - you are too vague about you need, and the code you showed is full of syntax errors. Editing/rewriting the question will help a lot.

Comment: I still don't get `v =  <li>`, is it supposed to be `v =  "<li>"`? Where is the code that composes `v` called?

Comment: @JamieStrauss: Unless you're in a closure, there's no such thing as sitting "globally to the loop" -- a variable is either global or function-level.  (And if you're using closures and don't get variable scope yet, you're in for some pain if you're not in it already.)  Either way, modifying `i` is not going to change the properties of everything that ever depended on its value.

Comment: @Igor - Syntax errors fixed.  What I would expect is for the console to log both "Property 1" and "Property 2", instead of "Property 1" twice.

Comment: @JamieStrauss - `v` is not reassigned inside the loop, how is it expected to change?

Comment: @Igor - Got it, scope issue I didn't understand.  Thanks, how can I marked as answered on a comment?

Comment: @JamieStrauss - I added an answer.

Comment: What you have posted is clearly not what you are running, since the posted code will throw and error at `v += array[i].prop,` since `array` does not exist yet. Further, the console will not log `0` as *i* is incremented before that occurs, so it will start at `1`. So even if you fix the logic flaw, the code will still not "work".

Comment: @JamieStrauss: No, that's no scope issue. Btw, you will need to increment `i` *after* the loop body instead of before it - you're retrieving `array[1]` and `array[2]` otherwise. Use `for`-loops like they were designed to be used, not like a `while` loop as you did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is not reassigned inside the loop. You append the same value multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your problem is, but in terms of "best way to do something" I would go:

```
var array = [
        {
            name: "1",
            prop: "Property 1"
        },
        {
            name: "2",
            prop: "Property 2"
        }   
    ],
    i = 0,
    v;
for (; i < array.length; i++) {
    v = '<li>' + array[i].prop + '</li>';
    $("body").append(v);
}
```

Comment: This is how its done, I only changed it to explicitly stated indexes to make the question clearer...